# unexpected behavior when reading a text file into array using javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

I am writing a emulator and I am trying to compare opcode logs from another working emulator. I have a log of executed opcodes ready to be compared it looks something like this

```
//log.txt (10000 lines long)
0
195
33
195
18...
```

I am reading this text file into a array using this code that looks kinda like this

```
//CPU.js
let log  = fs.readFileSync("./log.txt").toString().split("\n"); // read file
let logCount = 0;
function executeOP(){
let opcode = memoryRead(PC.inc()); // get opcode
  if(opcode != parseInt(log[logCount])){ // convert string to number and compare opcodes
    console.log("failed opcode " + log[logCount]); // print out failed opcode
    console.log("failed at line " + logCount); // print out failed opcode position
  }
  logCount++ // index of next opcode to compare
....
}
```

The problem is that parse in evaluates to NaN randomly on certain places in the test log array. It seems that extra invisible character example

```
console.log(log[2]) // 33
console.log(log[2][0]) // invisible
console.log(log[2].length) // 3? should be 2
```

I have tried correcting the array with (didn't work for me)

```
for(let i = 0; i < log.length; i++){
 log[i] = log[i].trim();
}
// also
for(let i = 0; i < log.length; i++){
 log[i] = log[i].replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,"");
}
```

similar issue thread [Loading text file in Javascript adds unexpected extra hidden characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25881102/loading-text-file-in-javascript-adds-unexpected-extra-hidden-characters)

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I've tried simple solution on replicated textfile and I don't really see any issue.

```js
const fs = reqiure('fs-extra')
const text = fs.readFileSync("./data.txt").toString().split("\r\n")

console.log(text[2][1]) // 3
```

Potential problem is with `\n` in your split function, in this code there is used `\r\n` to split these lines at glance, optionally you're able to use library dedicated for working on massive text-data, I've used that library for larger linear progression in `node.js` so maybe it will be useful for you, it's called `skale`.

Answer (score 0):

turn out it was a few zero width spaces very frustrating but a simple fix

```
    for(let i = 0; i < log.length; i++){
        log[i] = log[i].replace(/\u200B/g,"");
    }
```